# How to tell if your Likert scale score is LOW, AVERAGE, or HIGH?

Tags: likert, scales

I found that some Likert Scales doesn't tell you how much you should score to be considered in the LOW, AVERAGE, or HIGH margin? So how do we deal with these scales? If my score is 21 (for example) and the total score for the scale is 40, should we simply assume that since it's close to the middle then this must mean I have an AVERAGE score?

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated! Please consider adding (much) more information, either as reference or specific example.

Answer (score 1):

Without additional information there is no way to tell if any particular score is low, moderate or high; it's safe to assume that the minimum is not high and that the maximum is not low, but that's about it.

If the maximum is 40 then 21 could be very low, very high or anything in between.